# Error in exec master xp_cmdshell BCP queryout

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I need to create some XML from a SQL query. I need to increment a name file but with my code the system return the error

> Messaggio 102, livello 15, stato 1, riga 89
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

This error refers to the code part in

```
exec master.. `'+@num'+`
```

Below the code; the variable `@num` is of type `nvarchar`

```
SET @num = (SELECT CAST([incr_num] AS NVARCHAR(10)) FROM [DB01].[dbo].[NUM_XML])

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT @header,@inland FOR XML RAW(''''),ROOT(''root''), ELEMENTS, TYPE" queryout "\\server01\TEMP_SW\XML_TMS\test_'+@num+'.xml" -U xx -P xxxxx -c -C ANSI -t;'
```

I try to insert all path in another variable and attach this new variable in exec function, but the result not change

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Create command text first

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000) = 'bcp "SELECT @header,@inland FOR XML RAW(''''),ROOT(''root''), ELEMENTS, TYPE" queryout "\\server01\TEMP_SW\XML_TMS\test_'+@num+'.xml" -U xx -P xxxxx -c -C ANSI -t;' ;
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Comment: With your solution the system return the error

   Messaggio 214, livello 16, stato 201, procedura xp_cmdshell, riga 1 [riga iniziale del batch 0]
Procedure expects parameter 'command_string' of type 'varchar'.

Comment: please see my below answer. With your solution emerged another issue

Comment: @FrancescoIsetto .. This is another, xml-related problem, nothing to do with `xp_cmdshell`. Post it as another SO question, provide table definition and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Now if I execute the single query

```
SELECT @header,@inland FOR XML RAW(''),ROOT('root'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

I receive the correct XML data.

But if i insert the query into exec master..xp_cmdshell

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000) = 'bcp "SELECT @header,@inland FOR XML RAW(''''),ROOT(''root''), ELEMENTS, TYPE" queryout "\\server01\TEMP_SW\XML_TMS\test_'+@num+'.xml" -U xx -P xxxxx -c -C ANSI -t;' ;
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

The system return the error

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@header".
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
NULL
```

@header is declared as XML

Let me know thanks and regards